# Bootstrap.dat incorrect or no genesis block found

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, daemon, bootstrap.dat

Hi all i need to add bootstrap.dat after downloading i start bitcoind with `-loadblock` but not work i have error `Incorrect or no genesis block found. Wrong datadir for network?`

I start bitcoin with `./bitcoind -loadblock=/root/.bitcoin/bootstrap.dat` and connexion of my VPS are very slow what is the good solution ?

Its possible because bootstrap.dat are very big file ? And what is the difference between -reindex and tindex ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember exactly but i think all you need to do is put the bootstrap file in the data directory of bitcoin and then just start bitcoind.

However note that bootstrap is obsolete as of version 0.10 and downloading is faster and (disk usage lower) without it.

Don't waste too much time trying to get it to work if bandwidth is not costly for you.

Comment: Yes not work i tested in all folder but always is corrupted i wait for downloading all you think i need who many days for download all ? i have vps from ovh

Comment: Haven't tried a complete new download myself yet. I hear for some people it can be done in a ~8 hours. CPU can be a bottleneck too since all transactions needs to be verified.